# Why does the scene get darker when I add Point/ Spot/ Area Lights?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, hdri

See this image:
[image]

And now the same scene, with the internal lights:
[image]

Although the difference is quite clear, what bothers me most is that the curtains lose that light around the sunlight that hits them, this is where the problem becomes clearer.

I came to think that somehow they were really affecting the room by making it darker (which doesn't make sense to me), so I decided to do the test and add some Spot Lights far away from the room and this was the result.

Only with HDRI:
[image]

With 5 Spot Lights away from the house (The more lights I add, the more serious the problem becomes):
[image]

And finally with all the lights, where the problem gets even worse:
[image]

I'll also leave a .blend file with this last example for anyone who wants to take a look, but I don't understand how adding lights can make a scene darker.

I even thought about just leaving the HDR lighting, but some parts of the room would need spot lights to be visually more beautiful, so I'm still trying to understand what's happening.

Download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xfBw562nWxSestoOqwcmaGpGdysFKarA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

And this is in Cycles?

Without opening up your file, I would guess that its related to *Fast GI* approximation

[image]